# How to visualize architecture?

Tags: force.com

I'm reading through some code where data flows back and forth between class structures and sObjects through a business process. How do I diagram it visually?

UML's are for classes, ERD's are for objects, is there a representation for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago I have build a native tool that generate class diagrams out of Apex classes and SObjects. The generated diagrams are so called declarative UML (using [PlantUml](http://plantuml.com/classes.html) and can be easily extended for you specific purpose.

[image]

Feel free to check it out. It can be easily installed (but also forked and improved) on GitHub:
https://github.com/rsoesemann/plantuml4force

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after a data flow diagram, check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram)